# Wordpress Civi install keeps puking with "canary" and simplexml_load_file() error

Tags: wordpress, install

WP: 4.8.1
CIVI: 4.7.23
PHP 7.0.22ubuntu0.16.04.1
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Installation proceeds and then the CiviCrm page 500s.

```
[Sun Sep 03 17:24:57.841003 2017] [:error] [pid 2943] [client 24.1.98.245:49332] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file() in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Menu.php:116

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Menu.php(95): CRM_Core_Menu::read('/var/www/html/w...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Menu.php(175): CRM_Core_Menu::xmlItems(true)
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Menu.php(283): CRM_Core_Menu::items(true)
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(372): CRM_Core_Menu::store()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/System.php(49): CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches(1, 1)
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_system_flush(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169): Civi\\API\\Provider\\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Menu.php on line 116, referer: http://mackenzie.southsidescout.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=civicrm-install


[Sun Sep 03 17:25:10.472533 2017] [:error] [pid 2944] [client 24.1.98.245:49338] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA.

thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 53


[Sun Sep 03 17:25:21.322206 2017] [:error] [pid 13881] [client 24.1.98.245:49342] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA.

thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 53, referer: http://mackenzie.southsidescout.com/wp-admin/
```

Any thoughts?  Permissions appear clean

Comment: Thank you for posting this question and the answer! This is a good example of how just participating in Stack Exchange helps the community.  It took me just a few minutes to write a check for the PHP XML module, so less savvy folk than yourself won't have to experience this: [CRM-21142](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21142)

Comment: Jon, I'm thrilled to have helped out.  Thanks very much for your work on this amazing software.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that PHP did not have simplexml_load_file()  installed.  I ran

apt-get install php7.0-simplexml

Restarted apache and hosed the install in /plugins as well as its database, started over and now it has installed.